# How to redirect routes using Vue Router?

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

That is my first time using Vue.JS and I'm organizing my application by domains, for example, having a main router file I redirect some routes for properly domain.

```
               +--> /users +
               |           |         +-----------------+
+--------------+           |         |     +-----------+
|              |           |         |     |           |    + Profile
|  Index Page  |           |         |users        <--------+ Create
|              |           +-------> |     |           |
|              |                     |     +-----------+
+--------------+                     +-----------------+
```

inside `/users` there is a users-routes.js, which has:

```
const userRoutes = [
  {
    path: '/profile',
    component: () = import('./views/users/UserProfile')  
  }
];

export default userRoutes
```

Searching some codes, I have to apply inside my main routes:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Router from 'vue-router'
import { userRoutes } from './views/users/users-routes'

Vue.use(Router)

export default new Router({
  routes: [
    {
      path: '/',
      component: () => import('@/views/Index'),
      children: [
        // Dashboard
        {
          name: 'Dashboard',
          path: '',
          component: () => import('@/views/Dashboard'),
        },
      ],
    },
    {
      path: '/users',
      redirect: '/users',
    },
  ], 
  ...userRoutes
})
```

I receive two warning by pointing to `...userRoutes` line.

> 27:5   error  Trailing spaces not allowed  no-trailing-spaces
>   28:19  error  Missing trailing comma       comma-dangle

How Should I proceed?

Comment: One of the best way to handle vue routes/redirects- https://blog.logrocket.com/vue-middleware-pipelines/

Comment: The errors are linting errors: [no-trailing-spaces](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-trailing-spaces) and [comma-dangle](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/comma-dangle)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Obligatory, "I see you want to do A. A is bad. Do B instead."

The correct and simpler option is to keep the routes contained in the main `./src/router.js`, as the docs point out. From there, have a `vuex` value of `isLoggedIn`. Then in the `template` layer of "user" pages, do a `v-if` on if the user is logged in or not.

This can be taken a step further, and in the `created` hook, a check can be done if the user is logged in. And if they are not, the router can push the user to the login page (or whichever; Maybe you are using a login modal).